# How do I set the OnClickListener to Open a New Activity (or Page) for an ArrayList with an Adapter?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter, onclicklistener

I am trying to get each item in the array to open a page after a person clicks on them.

I have searched all over, but nothing works and it seems nothing answers my specific answer.  Here's my code:

---

```
 package com.projectexe;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState ) ; 

         ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
            String[] from = { "article", "description" };
          int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
            setListAdapter(adapter);            

    }



     private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            list.add(putData("Article 1", "Description 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nunc tellus, laoreet eu felis quis, hendrerit tincidunt turpis. Donec semper consequat erat, vel ornare odio tempus sed. Mauris sollicitudin libero dui, nec dignissim dolor tincidunt sit amet. Duis gravida lorem sed vestibulum vulputate. Etiam varius scelerisque vehicula."));
            list.add(putData("Article 2", "Description 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nunc tellus, laoreet eu felis quis, hendrerit tincidunt turpis. Donec semper consequat erat, vel ornare odio tempus sed. Mauris sollicitudin libero dui, nec dignissim dolor tincidunt sit amet. Duis gravida lorem sed vestibulum vulputate. Etiam varius scelerisque vehicula."));
            list.add(putData("Article 3", "Description 3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nunc tellus, laoreet eu felis quis, hendrerit tincidunt turpis. Donec semper consequat erat, vel ornare odio tempus sed. Mauris sollicitudin libero dui, nec dignissim dolor tincidunt sit amet. Duis gravida lorem sed vestibulum vulputate. Etiam varius scelerisque vehicula."));
            return list;


          }


          private HashMap<String, String> putData(String article, String description) {
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put("article", article);
            item.put("description", description);
            return item;
          }

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // Do something in response to the click

                     Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, DisplayMainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent1);             

                }
            }
```

---

```
package com.projectexe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DisplayMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_main);
          // Get the message from the intent


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_main,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    tools:context="com.projectexe.DisplayMainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >



</FrameLayout>
```

---

Console:

```
[2014-05-21 12:16:49 - ProjectExe] ------------------------------
[2014-05-21 12:16:49 - ProjectExe] Android Launch!
[2014-05-21 12:16:49 - ProjectExe] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-21 12:16:49 - ProjectExe] Performing com.projectexe.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-21 12:16:54 - ProjectExe] Launch canceled!
[2014-05-21 12:22:42 - ProjectExe] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-05-21 12:22:45 - ProjectExe] ------------------------------
[2014-05-21 12:22:45 - ProjectExe] Android Launch!
[2014-05-21 12:22:45 - ProjectExe] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-21 12:22:45 - ProjectExe] Performing com.projectexe.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-21 12:22:49 - ProjectExe] ------------------------------
[2014-05-21 12:22:49 - ProjectExe] Android Launch!
[2014-05-21 12:22:49 - ProjectExe] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-21 12:22:49 - ProjectExe] Performing com.projectexe.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-21 12:22:54 - ProjectExe] Launch canceled!
[2014-05-21 12:22:56 - ProjectExe] Launch canceled!
[2014-05-21 12:41:17 - ProjectExe] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-05-21 12:41:19 - ProjectExe] ------------------------------
[2014-05-21 12:41:19 - ProjectExe] Android Launch!
[2014-05-21 12:41:19 - ProjectExe] adb is running normally.
[2014-05-21 12:41:19 - ProjectExe] Performing com.projectexe.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-05-21 12:41:26 - ProjectExe] Launch canceled!
```

When the clickListener is touched, I want it to use an intent to start a new activity. If I add code that says, OnClickListener, and I add the intent--my app crashes. The last time, I just tried to add toast and it showed the listview, but when I tapped the first item it crashed. I do not want a toast, I just want it to go to a new page or activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added any log cat with an exception nor the onClickListener code in question so I can't be entirely sure why your app is crashing (it could be incorrect intent etc.), but I imagine you are trying to add the click listener to the listview, what you need is an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) instead

**EDIT**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState ); 
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "article", "description" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);            
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMainActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I updated the code with what I am using for the click listener. What I initially posted worked without any issues, but when I add this it works but when I click whatever's in the ArrayList, nothing happens. It's not crashing with this code, it just doesn't do anything. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Have you added some logging / debugged to see what is happening behind the scenes when clicking an item. I'm going to edit my answer and add some code, because what you are doing looks wrong

Comment: Um, no. I just update the code, and put the .apk on my phone using dropbox. The emulator doesn't work on my computer. Oh and I got the click listener code from here (Android Developer site): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews  

I added the intent myself.

Comment: Hi Nick, so when I updated it with your code, it crashes when I select an item. The array appears normally, but when I select it, it freezes.

Comment: OMG NICK! WE DID IT! I am so over the moon excited! wahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I changed [this] to MainActivity.class and it works! You are AWESOME! Should I update the original code to show the working code? How do I thumbs you up? lol This is my first time posting a question, so I'm not sure how this works now! Thank you so much! I have spent a MONTH on trying to figure this out!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: there should be a tick to the left of my answer you can press to accept, and the grey up triangle above that to vote. Glad it helped

Comment: Absolutely. I am going to share your website on my social media networks also. Keep up the great work! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, glad you're enjoying Android now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OnItemClickListener. It helps you perform actions for specific item clicks.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work. I used this and it doesn't work:  

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           // Do something in response to the click
        
         Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, DisplayMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);      
                    
       }

Comment: I updated the code with the click listener I used. It doesn't do anything!